# Symfony2 : How to get value from array and print it into twing file

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony. I am currently using symfony2.4 .

where I stuck -

I have one scenario. In which I have to show simple listing in twing file. The data comes from database. This data comes from the two joined tables.

First table is **Teams**

id

name

nickname

country_id

Second table is **Country**

id

name

I want to print data like this

```
     Name     | Nickname | Country(name)

Mumbai Indians| MI       | India
New Royals    | NR       | India
```

So What I do in my twing file :

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Nickname</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
{% for team in teams %}
  <tr>
      <td>{{ team.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ team.nickname }}</td>
      <td>{{ team.country }}</td> <<<<<<<<<<<
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So Here **country is not working**

This is my controller code

```
$teams = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AdminSporteventsBundle:Teams')
                ->findAll();

        if (!$teams) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No news found');
        }
        $build['teams'] = $teams;
        return $this->render('AdminSporteventsBundle:Teams:teams_list.html.twig', $build);
```

**EDIT**

As requested Teams.php (Entity)

```
namespace Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Teams
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="teams", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="uq_teams_name_sport_id", columns={"sport_id", "name"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_teams_by_sport_id", columns={"sport_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_teams_by_sport_id_country_id", columns={"sport_id", "country_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_teams_not_deleted", columns={"deleted"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_96C22258F92F3E70", columns={"country_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_96C222581177C375", columns={"information_page_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_96C222586D947EBB", columns={"logo_image_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Teams
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="team_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="teams_team_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $teamId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $deleted;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="editable_pages_page_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $editablePagesPageId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nickname", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nickname;

    /**
     * @var \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id")
     * })
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\InformationPages
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\InformationPages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="information_page_id", referencedColumnName="information_page_id")
     * })
     */
    private $informationPage;

    /**
     * @var \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Images
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="logo_image_id", referencedColumnName="image_id")
     * })
     */
    private $logoImage;

    /**
     * @var \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Sports
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Sports")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sport_id", referencedColumnName="sport_id")
     * })
     */
    private $sport;



    /**
     * Get teamId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTeamId()
    {
        return $this->teamId;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set deleted
     *
     * @param boolean $deleted
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setDeleted($deleted)
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deleted
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getDeleted()
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set editablePagesPageId
     *
     * @param integer $editablePagesPageId
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setEditablePagesPageId($editablePagesPageId)
    {
        $this->editablePagesPageId = $editablePagesPageId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get editablePagesPageId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEditablePagesPageId()
    {
        return $this->editablePagesPageId;
    }

    /**
     * Set nickname
     *
     * @param string $nickname
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setNickname($nickname)
    {
        $this->nickname = $nickname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nickname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNickname()
    {
        return $this->nickname;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries $country
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setCountry(\Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries $country = null)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries 
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * Set informationPage
     *
     * @param \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\InformationPages $informationPage
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setInformationPage(\Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\InformationPages $informationPage = null)
    {
        $this->informationPage = $informationPage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get informationPage
     *
     * @return \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\InformationPages 
     */
    public function getInformationPage()
    {
        return $this->informationPage;
    }

    /**
     * Set logoImage
     *
     * @param \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Images $logoImage
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setLogoImage(\Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Images $logoImage = null)
    {
        $this->logoImage = $logoImage;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logoImage
     *
     * @return \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Images 
     */
    public function getLogoImage()
    {
        return $this->logoImage;
    }

    /**
     * Set sport
     *
     * @param \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Sports $sport
     * @return Teams
     */
    public function setSport(\Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Sports $sport = null)
    {
        $this->sport = $sport;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sport
     *
     * @return \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Sports 
     */
    public function getSport()
    {
        return $this->sport;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

EDIT Countries.php (Entity)

namespace Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Countries
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="countries", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="uq_countries_name", columns={"name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Countries
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="countries_country_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $countryId;

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $name;



/**
 * Get countryId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getCountryId()
{
    return $this->countryId;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Countries
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your Entity code for 'Teams'

Comment: Do you have the country stored as a string or is related to another entity?

Comment: Do you have a __toString method in your country entity class?

Comment: @sglessard : yes. __toString method is their

Comment: @BobFlemming : Entity Code Pasted

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `{{ team.country.name }}` assuming you have set your relationships up properly.

Updated to reflect entity code.

Comment: Now It is not throwing error. but not showing anything

Comment: I think you are so close

Comment: In your controller what happens if you do foreach($teams as $team) {  print_r($team->getCountry()->getName()) }

Comment: May be I think no data come for name. Is that any extra code in controller to get this name? Please check my controller code.

Comment: Do the Teams have Counties associated with them in the DB? Are the joins in place in your schema?

Comment: Yes they are associated in schema

Comment: {{ team.country.countryId }} prints Country id then why {{ team.country.name }} does not work ? Is it anything need like this - {{ team.country.name.string }} (because of __toString() method) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yo have mistake in the teams entity at join column annotation. Referencedcolumn generally is id(what's your country primary key).  Then try to access country like this

You need to do {{ team.country.name }} in twig assuming you have set your relationships up proper

Comment: No It is not working. My insert is working fine so it is setup ed properly

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
/**
 * @var \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id")
 * })
 */
private $country;
```

need to be changed to:

```
/**
 * @var \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $country;
```

as `referencedColumnName` should be `id`, not `country_id`

By doing as above, you will create the relationship properly then in your twig file, you can use:

`{{ team.country.name }}`

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Teams Entity , at the $country field, try using the following to set the relationship:

```
/**
 * @var \Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\SporteventsBundle\Entity\Countries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="country_id")
 */
private $country;
```

and then you can access the name of your country by typing the following in twig:

```
{{ team.country.name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's an array , and you must scan it?

```html
{% for country in team.country %}
  {{ country.name }}
{% endfor %}
```